# iFrame to change on button click on Parent

Tags: html, iframe

I have a parent page that contains buttons. I would like to change the iframe page on a click of the main buttons.

My code is as follow for the iframe:

```
      <iframe id="etrack_main" 
              src="iframe/etrack/menu.php" 
              frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="yes"
              onload="resizeIframe(this); "></iframe>
```

The button code is as follow:

```
  <div class="col-xs-2">
      <button type="button" 
              class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-block"
              onClick="location.href='iframe/etrack/search.php'"
              target="etrack_main">Client Checks
      </button>
  </div>
```

It opens the iFrame in a new page but not using the parent page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the below code in place of `...location.href=...`

```
onClick="document.getElementById('etrack_main').src='iframe/etrack/search.php'"
```